# Google hybrid ( openid + oauth) protocol doesn`t work for 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, oauth, gmail, openid, google-openid

Im trying to implement google hybrid protocol (oauth over openid).
And the problem that google doesn`t ask for oauth permission( trying with gmail), only openid.
I registered at google api console:

```
Client ID for web applications
Client ID: 248141267047.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address:248141267047@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret: 
Redirect URIs:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback
JavaScript origins:     http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Here is my python code for generating openid url:

```
class OpenIDOAuthRequest(Extension):

    ns_alias = 'oauth'

    def __init__(self, consumer, scope, ns_uri=None):
        Extension.__init__(self)
        self.consumer = consumer
        self.scope = scope
        self.ns_uri = ns_uri or oauth_ns_uri

    def getExtensionArgs(self):
        return {
            'consumer': self.consumer,
            'scope': ' '.join(self.scope),
        }


def google():
        #define google openid url
        openid_session = {}
        openid_store = filestore.FileOpenIDStore('.')
        consumer = Consumer(openid_session, openid_store)
        openid = u"https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"
        URLS = {
            'ax_last': "http://axschema.org/namePerson/last",
            'ax_first': "http://axschema.org/namePerson/first",
            'ax_email': "http://axschema.org/contact/email",
            "country":"http://axschema.org/contact/country/home",
            "timezone":"http://axschema.org/pref/timezone",
            "language":"http://axschema.org/pref/language",
            "person":"http://axschema.org/namePerson",
        }
        #defining what fields we're going to get
        ax_request = ax.FetchRequest()
        for k,v in URLS.iteritems():
            ax_request.add(ax.AttrInfo(v, required = True))
        oa = OpenIDOAuthRequest("248141267047.apps.googleusercontent.com",["https://mail.google.com/",])
        try:
            authrequest = consumer.begin(openid)
        except DiscoveryFailure, e:
            print e
            print "some errror happened"
        else:
            authrequest.addExtension(ax_request)
            authrequest.addExtension(oa)



        redirecturl = authrequest.redirectURL("http://127.0.0.1:8000",
            return_to = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback",
            immediate=False)
        print redirecturl
```

It generates following url:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9Vr6Biwp-rCAr4TLbf8CtItR-zr3bs0LT7oYQ3Pakg93ivCS_6C&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=ext0,ext1,ext2,ext3,ext4,ext5,ext6&openid.ax.type.ext0=http://axschema.org/contact/email&openid.ax.type.ext1=http://axschema.org/namePerson&openid.ax.type.ext2=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first&openid.ax.type.ext3=http://axschema.org/pref/timezone&openid.ax.type.ext4=http://axschema.org/pref/language&openid.ax.type.ext5=http://axschema.org/contact/country/home&openid.ax.type.ext6=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.ns.ax=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0&openid.oauth.consumer=248141267047.apps.googleusercontent.com&openid.oauth.scope=https://mail.google.com/&openid.realm=http://127.0.0.1:8000&openid.return_to=http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback?janrain_nonce%3D2012-05-01T22%253A50%253A33ZUW7vcj
```

And it has all necessary extensions. But if i go to this url it doesnt ask me permission for gmail. Also i was comparing to similar url from sanebox.com. And it works as expected, asking for permission for gmail. But i didnt see any essential difference why their url is working and mine is not. Futhermore, i replaced 127.0.0.1 in my url to sanebox urls, and left other parts same. And ... now it`s asking for permission for gmail. Switch back to 127.0.0.1 - stops asking . Here is sanebox url:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth?openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9UV4Ud714HHaFJ0fpItabA8v-zw0QuReEPcn61ilJzyFrFia5PO&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=ext0,ext1,ext2,ext3,ext4,ext5,ext6&openid.ax.type.ext0=http://axschema.org/pref/timezone&openid.ax.type.ext1=http://axschema.org/contact/country/home&openid.ax.type.ext2=http://axschema.org/pref/language&openid.ax.type.ext3=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last&openid.ax.type.ext4=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first&openid.ax.type.ext5=http://axschema.org/namePerson&openid.ax.type.ext6=http://axschema.org/contact/email&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.ns.ax=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0&openid.ns.sreg=http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1&openid.oauth.consumer=www.sanebox.com&openid.oauth.scope=https://mail.google.com/+http://www.google.com/m8/feeds&openid.realm=https://www.sanebox.com/&openid.return_to=https://www.sanebox.com/users?_method%3Dpost%26open_id_complete%3D1
```

So what i am missing? Why it doesnt work for 127.0.0.1 if i regestered this url in api console. And it was working fine  with openid. And was working fine with oauth itself without openid. But now when i try to use oauth over openid it doesn`t ask me for permission to gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I had run the PHP, ASP, DOT NET codes they are running absolutely fine and thus sure that the python app will also run correctly. You must be changing the default app. First run the default app provided by them and try to change. If there default app doesn't work then to   can also open a bug report to google.

Comment: The problem is only with running it with 127.0.0.1. I ended up with adding needed domain to hosts file. And the default app doesn`t exist for hybrid protocol for python. Only lib for openid that i`m already using

Comment: @Aldarund IT worked for me even on localhost i.e 127.0.0.1 for me

Comment: I posted two links , you can try to open them both. Link with localhost wouldn`t ask you for gmail access, while link with normal domain will do that. THe only difference between links is domain.

Comment: Two this I had noticed, 1. Where is your client secret in the code of sending request. 2. The scoops are not defined properly. Where are openid ns claimed_id identity mode oauth scope realm. Kindly read the Open Id Specification First then try to Implement the same

Comment: 1. The client secret goes later, not when we generate a url. 2. Scopes are defined properly.. This code is 100% working. It work without any errors on a real site right now.

Comment: Kindly provide your consumer name as provided and change the returning url to local host then try it.